# User-friendly time format in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, date, time, formatting

Python: I need to show file modification times in the "1 day ago", "two hours ago", format.

Is there something ready to do that? It should be in English.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

The code was originally published on a blog post "Python Pretty Date function" (http://evaisse.com/post/93417709/python-pretty-date-function)

It is reproduced here as the blog account has been suspended and the page is no longer available.

```
def pretty_date(time=False):
    """
    Get a datetime object or a int() Epoch timestamp and return a
    pretty string like 'an hour ago', 'Yesterday', '3 months ago',
    'just now', etc
    """
    from datetime import datetime
    now = datetime.now()
    if type(time) is int:
        diff = now - datetime.fromtimestamp(time)
    elif isinstance(time, datetime):
        diff = now - time
    elif not time:
        diff = 0
    second_diff = diff.seconds
    day_diff = diff.days

    if day_diff < 0:
        return ''

    if day_diff == 0:
        if second_diff < 10:
            return "just now"
        if second_diff < 60:
            return str(second_diff) + " seconds ago"
        if second_diff < 120:
            return "a minute ago"
        if second_diff < 3600:
            return str(second_diff // 60) + " minutes ago"
        if second_diff < 7200:
            return "an hour ago"
        if second_diff < 86400:
            return str(second_diff // 3600) + " hours ago"
    if day_diff == 1:
        return "Yesterday"
    if day_diff < 7:
        return str(day_diff) + " days ago"
    if day_diff < 31:
        return str(day_diff // 7) + " weeks ago"
    if day_diff < 365:
        return str(day_diff // 30) + " months ago"
    return str(day_diff // 365) + " years ago"
```

Comment: that is tailored to my exact needs. Thanks!

Comment: The link no longer exists and is giving a Forbidden. Need a permlink here or the content to be moved into this post.

Comment: @Chris: Thanks for the heads up, and it was still in Google Cache so I snagged it.

Comment: This does not work for me. I get this error: local variable 'diff' referenced before assignment why?

Comment: I threw this up to the cheeseshop: (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/human_dates/0.1.0) and https://github.com/jtushman/human_dates

Comment: It would be nice if the time units were not pluralized for single counts, for example '1 week ago' rather than '1 weeks ago'

Comment: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'diff' referenced before assignment

Comment: What is the point of the code `diff = now - now`. Cant we do instead `diff = 0`

Comment: @Jonathan I tried human_dates 0.2.0 and got: 2.76986301369863 years ago .   I found a version in django at https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/timesince.py  which gives me:  2 years, 9 months

Comment: @wenbert because in python 3 mtime is of type `float`, not of type `int`. In the first if, change `int` to `float`.

Comment: The link appears broken again, not 404 but rather a sales page in foreign language.

Answer (score 33):

If you happen to be using [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/), then new in version 1.4 is the `naturaltime` template filter.

To use it, first add `'django.contrib.humanize'` to your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting in settings.py, and `{% load humanize %}` into the template you're using the filter in.

Then, in your template, if you have a datetime variable `my_date`, you can print its distance from the present by using `{{ my_date|naturaltime }}`, which will be rendered as something like `4 minutes ago`.

[Other new things in Django 1.4.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/)

[Documentation for `naturaltime` and other filters in the `django.contrib.humanize` set.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/humanize/)

Comment: Is adding it to INSTALLED_APPS really necessary? It worked without that for me, although I used the filter inside python, not the template

Comment: Can I use this inside view

Answer (score 16):

In looking for the same thing with the additional requirement that it handle future dates, I found this: 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/py-pretty/1

Example code (from site):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
now = datetime.now()
hrago = now - timedelta(hours=1)
yesterday = now - timedelta(days=1)
tomorrow = now + timedelta(days=1)
dayafter = now + timedelta(days=2)

import pretty
print pretty.date(now)                      # 'now'
print pretty.date(hrago)                    # 'an hour ago'
print pretty.date(hrago, short=True)        # '1h ago'
print pretty.date(hrago, asdays=True)       # 'today'
print pretty.date(yesterday, short=True)    # 'yest'
print pretty.date(tomorrow)                 # 'tomorrow'
```

Comment: Unfortunately py-pretty does not seem to allow i18n.

Answer (score 12):

You can also do that with [arrow](https://arrow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) package

From [github page](https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow):

> ```
> >>> import arrow
> >>> utc = arrow.utcnow()
> >>> utc = utc.shift(hours=-1)
> >>> utc.humanize()
> 'an hour ago'
> ```

Answer (score 8):

There is [`humanize` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/humanize):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> import humanize # $ pip install humanize
>>> humanize.naturaltime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
'a day ago'
>>> humanize.naturaltime(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2))
'2 hours ago'
```

It supports localization [l10n](/questions/tagged/l10n), internationalization [i18n](/questions/tagged/i18n):

```
>>> _ = humanize.i18n.activate('ru_RU')
>>> print humanize.naturaltime(datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1))
день назад
>>> print humanize.naturaltime(datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=2))
2 часа назад
```

Comment: Note that `humanize` does not support timezone-aware datetimes; you’ll have to convert those via into naive ones (in the local timezone) with `dt.astimezone().replace(tzinfo=None)`.

Answer (score 6):

The answer Jed Smith linked to is good, and I used it for a year or so, but I think it could be improved in a few ways:

- It's nice to be able to define each time unit in terms of the preceding unit, instead of having "magic" constants like 3600, 86400, etc. sprinkled throughout the code.
- After much use, I find I don't want to go to the next unit quite so eagerly.  Example: both 7 days and 13 days will show as "1 week"; I'd rather see "7 days" or "13 days" instead.

Here's what I came up with:

```
def PrettyRelativeTime(time_diff_secs):
    # Each tuple in the sequence gives the name of a unit, and the number of
    # previous units which go into it.
    weeks_per_month = 365.242 / 12 / 7
    intervals = [('minute', 60), ('hour', 60), ('day', 24), ('week', 7),
                 ('month', weeks_per_month), ('year', 12)]

    unit, number = 'second', abs(time_diff_secs)
    for new_unit, ratio in intervals:
        new_number = float(number) / ratio
        # If the new number is too small, don't go to the next unit.
        if new_number < 2:
            break
        unit, number = new_unit, new_number
    shown_num = int(number)
    return '{} {}'.format(shown_num, unit + ('' if shown_num == 1 else 's'))
```

Notice how every tuple in `intervals` is easy to interpret and check: a `'minute'` is `60` seconds; an `'hour'` is `60` minutes; etc.  The only fudge is setting `weeks_per_month` to its average value; given the application, that should be fine.  (And note that it's clear at a glance that the last three constants multiply out to 365.242, the number of days per year.)

One downside to my function is that it doesn't do anything outside the "## units" pattern: "Yesterday", "just now", etc. are right out.  Then again, the original poster didn't ask for these fancy terms, so I prefer my function for its succinctness and the readability of its numerical constants. :)

Comment: Nice solution. Keeping it simple allows more reuse. E.g can use suffix for relative time `value + " ago"` or duration `value + " left"`

Answer (score 4):

The [ago](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ago) package provides this.  Call `human` on a `datetime` object to get a human readable description of the difference.

```
from ago import human
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

ts = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1, hours=5)

print(human(ts))
# 1 day, 5 hours ago

print(human(ts, precision=1))
# 1 day ago
```

Answer (score 2):

Using datetime objects with tzinfo:

```
def time_elapsed(etime):
    # need to add tzinfo to datetime.utcnow
    now = datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=etime.tzinfo)
    opened_for = (now - etime).total_seconds()
    names = ["seconds","minutes","hours","days","weeks","months"]
    modulos = [ 1,60,3600,3600*24,3600*24*7,3660*24*30]
    values = []
    for m in modulos[::-1]:
        values.append(int(opened_for / m))
        opened_for -= values[-1]*m
    pretty = [] 
    for i,nm in enumerate(names[::-1]):
        if values[i]!=0:
            pretty.append("%i %s" % (values[i],nm))
    return " ".join(pretty)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written a detailed blog post for the solution on http://sunilarora.org/17329071
I am posting a quick snippet here as well.

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

def get_fancy_time(d, display_full_version = False):
    """Returns a user friendly date format
    d: some datetime instace in the past
    display_second_unit: True/False
    """
    #some helpers lambda's
    plural = lambda x: 's' if x > 1 else ''
    singular = lambda x: x[:-1]
    #convert pluran (years) --> to singular (year)
    display_unit = lambda unit, name: '%s %s%s'%(unit, name, plural(unit)) if unit > 0 else ''

    #time units we are interested in descending order of significance
    tm_units = ['years', 'months', 'days', 'hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']

    rdelta = relativedelta(datetime.utcnow(), d) #capture the date difference
    for idx, tm_unit in enumerate(tm_units):
        first_unit_val = getattr(rdelta, tm_unit)
        if first_unit_val > 0:
            primary_unit = display_unit(first_unit_val, singular(tm_unit))
            if display_full_version and idx < len(tm_units)-1:
                next_unit = tm_units[idx + 1]
                second_unit_val = getattr(rdelta, next_unit)
                if second_unit_val > 0:
                    secondary_unit = display_unit(second_unit_val, singular(next_unit))
                    return primary_unit + ', '  + secondary_unit
            return primary_unit
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DAY_INCREMENTS = [
    [365, "year"],
    [30, "month"],
    [7, "week"],
    [1, "day"],
]

SECOND_INCREMENTS = [
    [3600, "hour"],
    [60, "minute"],
    [1, "second"],
]


def time_ago(dt):
    diff = datetime.now() - dt  # use timezone.now() or equivalent if `dt` is timezone aware
    if diff.days < 0:
        return "in the future?!?"
    for increment, label in DAY_INCREMENTS:
        if diff.days >= increment:
            increment_diff = int(diff.days / increment)
            return str(increment_diff) + " " + label + plural(increment_diff) + " ago"
    for increment, label in SECOND_INCREMENTS:
        if diff.seconds >= increment:
            increment_diff = int(diff.seconds / increment)
            return str(increment_diff) + " " + label + plural(increment_diff) + " ago"
    return "just now"


def plural(num):
    if num != 1:
        return "s"
    return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the gist of @sunil 's post

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
>>> then = datetime(2003, 9, 17, 20, 54, 47, 282310)
>>> relativedelta(then, datetime.now())
relativedelta(years=-11, months=-3, days=-9, hours=-18, minutes=-17, seconds=-8, microseconds=+912664)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install from below link. It should be more helpful for you. It has been providing user friendly message from second to year.

It's well tested.

https://github.com/nareshchaudhary37/timestamp_content

Below steps to install into your virtual env.

```
git clone https://github.com/nareshchaudhary37/timestamp_content
cd timestamp-content
python setup.py
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an updated answer based on Jed Smith's implementation that properly hands both offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes. You can also give a default timezones. Python 3.5+.

```
import datetime

def pretty_date(time=None, default_timezone=datetime.timezone.utc):
    """
    Get a datetime object or a int() Epoch timestamp and return a
    pretty string like 'an hour ago', 'Yesterday', '3 months ago',
    'just now', etc
    """

    # Assumes all timezone naive dates are UTC
    if time.tzinfo is None or time.tzinfo.utcoffset(time) is None:
        if default_timezone:
            time = time.replace(tzinfo=default_timezone)

    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)

    if type(time) is int:
        diff = now - datetime.fromtimestamp(time)
    elif isinstance(time, datetime.datetime):
        diff = now - time
    elif not time:
        diff = now - now
    second_diff = diff.seconds
    day_diff = diff.days

    if day_diff < 0:
        return ''

    if day_diff == 0:
        if second_diff < 10:
            return "just now"
        if second_diff < 60:
            return str(second_diff) + " seconds ago"
        if second_diff < 120:
            return "a minute ago"
        if second_diff < 3600:
            return str(second_diff / 60) + " minutes ago"
        if second_diff < 7200:
            return "an hour ago"
        if second_diff < 86400:
            return str(second_diff / 3600) + " hours ago"
    if day_diff == 1:
        return "Yesterday"
    if day_diff < 7:
        return str(day_diff) + " days ago"
    if day_diff < 31:
        return str(day_diff / 7) + " weeks ago"
    if day_diff < 365:
        return str(day_diff / 30) + " months ago"
    return str(day_diff / 365) + " years ago"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been dragging and tweaking this code from programming language to programming language for so long, I don't remember where I originally got it from. It served me well in PHP, Java, and TypeScript, and now it's time for Python.

It handles past and future dates, as well as edge cases.

```
def unix_time() -> int:
    return int(time.time())


def pretty_time(t: int, absolute=False) -> str:
    if not type(t) is int:
        return "N/A"
    if t == 0:
        return "Never"

    now = unix_time()
    if t == now:
        return "Now"

    periods = ["second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade"]
    lengths = [60, 60, 24, 7, 4.35, 12, 10]

    diff = now - t

    if absolute:
        suffix = ""
    else:
        if diff >= 0:
            suffix = "ago"
        else:
            diff *= -1
            suffix = "remaining"

    i = 0
    while diff >= lengths[i] and i < len(lengths) - 1:
        diff /= lengths[i]
        i += 1

    diff = round(diff)
    if diff > 1:
        periods[i] += "s"

    return "{0} {1} {2}".format(diff, periods[i], suffix)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def time_ago(self):
        start_time = self.date # The start date
        now_time = datetime.now()

        difference = int((now_time - start_time).total_seconds())

        second = [1, 'seconds']
        minute = [60, 'minutes']
        hour = [60 * minute[0], 'hours']
        day = [24 * hour[0], 'days']
        week = [7 * day[0], 'weeks']
        month = [4 * week[0], 'months']
        year = [12 * month[0], 'years']

        times = [year, month, week, day, hour, minute, second]
        for time in times:
            if difference >= time[0]:
                time_ago = int(difference / time[0])
                if time_ago <= 1:
                    timeframe = time[1].rstrip('s')
                else:
                    timeframe = time[1]

                time_item = str(time_ago) + ' ' + timeframe
                return time_item
        return 'Date Error'
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt at writing a clear and short function. Alternatively, you can do `diff = dt.datetime.now() - past`

```py
import datetime as dt

def human_time_ago(now: dt.datetime, past: dt.datetime) -> str:
    """Return time difference as human-readable string"""
    periods = (
        ("year", 60 * 60 * 24 * 365),
        ("month", 60 * 60 * 24 * 30),
        ("week", 60 * 60 * 24 * 7),
        ("day", 60 * 60 * 24),
        ("hour", 60 * 60),
        ("minute", 60),
    )
    diff = now - past

    for period, seconds_each in periods:
        if diff.total_seconds() >= seconds_each:
            how_many = int(diff.total_seconds() / seconds_each)
            return f"{how_many} {period}{'s' if how_many >= 2 else ''} ago"

    return "just now"  # less than a minute ago
```